# How to resolve Xamarin iOS SecKeyChain InteractionNotAllowed issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin.iOS project I used SecRecord/SecKeyChain to store my token values and app version. From production log I found keychain related exceptions with status code 'InteractionNotAllowed'  when try to write/read items in keychain. Apple documents states that to resolve InteractionNotAllowed error we need to change the default kSecAttrAccessible attribute value from ‘**WhenUnlocked**' to ‘**Always**’. 
But in my existing code when I changed accessible attribute to '**Always**' app log out because it failed to read token from keychain. It return’s '**Item not found**' when read. But when I tried to save token again it returns '**Duplicate item**'. So again I tried to remove same item but this time it again returns '**Item not found**'. That’s really strange I can’t delete it and I can’t read it with same key.

Below is the code snippet -

```
private SecRecord CreateRecordForNewKeyValue(string accountName, string value)
        {
            return new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
            {
                Service = App.AppName,
                Account = accountName,
                ValueData = NSData.FromString(value, NSStringEncoding.UTF8),
                Accessible = SecAccessible.Always //This line of code is newly added.
            };
        }



private SecRecord ExistingRecordForKey(string accountName)
        {
            return new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
            {
                Service = App.AppName,
                Account = accountName,
                Accessible = SecAccessible.Always //This line of code is newly added. 
            };
        }



public void SetValueForKeyAndAccount(string value, string accountName, string key)
        {
            var record = ExistingRecordForKey(accountName);
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetValueFromAccountAndKey(accountName, key)))
                        RemoveRecord(record);
                    return;
                }
                // if the key already exists, remove it before set value
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetValueFromAccountAndKey(accountName, key)))
                    RemoveRecord(record);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Log exception here -("RemoveRecord Failed " + accountName, e,);
            }
            //Adding new record values to keychain
            var result = SecKeyChain.Add(CreateRecordForNewKeyValue(accountName, value));
            if (result != SecStatusCode.Success)
            {
                if (result == SecStatusCode.DuplicateItem)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Log exception here -("Error adding record: {0} for Account-" + accountName, result), "Try Remove account");
                        RemoveRecord(record);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //Log exception here -("RemoveRecord Failed  after getting error SecStatusCode.DuplicateItem for Account-" + accountName, e);
                    } 
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Error adding record: {0} for Account-" + accountName, result));
            }
        }    


public string GetValueFromAccountAndKey(string accountName, string key)
        {
            try
            {
                var record = ExistingRecordForKey(accountName);
                SecStatusCode resultCode;
                var match = SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord(record, out resultCode);
                if (resultCode == SecStatusCode.Success)
                {
                    if (match.ValueData != null)
                    {
                        string valueData = NSString.FromData(match.ValueData, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueData))
                            return string.Empty;
                        return valueData;
                    }
                    else if (match.Generic != null)
                    {
                        string valueData = NSString.FromData(match.ValueData, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueData))
                            return string.Empty;
                        return valueData;
                    }
                    else
                        return string.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Exception logged here -("iOS Keychain Error for account-" + accountName, e);
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The property `Service` is also an unique identification when we store or retrieve data using **KeyChain**. You didn't post your `GetValueFromAccountAndKey()` method, so we don't know what is the `key` used for? But in your case, you should use the same `Service` to retrieve value:

```
string GetValueFromAccountAndKey(string accoundName, string service)
{
    var securityRecord = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
    {
        Service = service,
        Account = accoundName
    };

    SecStatusCode status;
    NSData resultData = SecKeyChain.QueryAsData(securityRecord, false, out status);

    var result = resultData != null ? new NSString(resultData, NSStringEncoding.UTF8) : "Not found";

    return result;
}
```

Since you just make a hard code in your `CreateRecordForNewKeyValue()`( the Service has been written as a constant ), if you want to retrieve your value you should also set the `Service` as `App.AppName` in the method `GetValueFromAccountAndKey()`.

> It return’s 'Item not found' when read. But when I tried to save token
>   again it returns 'Duplicate item'.

This is because when we use the same `Account` but different `Service` to retrieve data, KeyChain can't find the corresponding `SecRecord`. This made you thought the `SecRecord` didn't exist, then use the same `Account` to store value. The `Duplicate item` result throws out. For a `SecRecord`, the `Account` and `Service` must both be unique.

Comment: -Thanks. I am not using key value any where in GetValueFromAccountAndKey function. (Key passed to avoid build error in Android. It's shared code called via dependency service ). I updated my get value code for your reference. I used same service name also. The problem occurs when I added Accessible = SecAccessible.Always in CreateRecordForNewKeyValue and ExistingRecordForKey functions.

Comment: @Vishnu I used your `GetValueFromAccountAndKey ()`, the stored data can be retrieved. Then if I write a new value, the old record will be removed. [Here](https://github.com/landl0526/KeyChainDemo) is my sample, it worked well. Did I miss something?

Comment: @ Land Lu - MSFT Do one thing in the code please comment or remove 'Accessible = SecAccessible.Always' from both 'ExistingRecordForKey' and 'CreateRecordForNewKeyValue' functions. Then run the code and save one data. Now add 'Accessible = SecAccessible.Always' in both functions and run the code. Try to read already saved data. This time I believe this strange behaviour happens.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue ?

Comment: I test what you said above, comment `Accessible = SecAccessible.Always`. But read and write both work well using my sample.

Comment: On the same code now uncomment Accessible = SecAccessible.Always and run the code. Please try to read previously saved data (data you saved with code comment).

Comment: I erase my simulator and try again. Without `Accessible = SecAccessible.Always` it works fine, then add this code the issue occurs. But why you want to add and remove it? Usually if without it you can't read and write then add it erase your emulator, test it. There's no need to add and remove it again and again.

Comment: Actually in my existing code (already app deployed to app store) is without  Accessible attribute value. So it takes default value (SecAccessible.WhenUnlocked). This will cause 'InteractionNotAllowed' error. To resolve this issue I add Accessible = SecAccessible.Always to my existing code. This leads to log out my existing users.

Comment: Maybe it will cause your issues, but for other devices just use your code with `Accessible = SecAccessible.Always` included this issue will never occur. Also for your device erase it and restart the keychain will resolve it. You just need to upload the code with `Accessible = SecAccessible.Always`. Moreover without this code, we can also read and write data to keychain.

Comment: This is not only for my device. All users who download app from app store and logged in successfully will face this issue, if I changed my code and submit new version of app to app store. My main intension is to resolve 'InteractionNotAllowed' issue.

Comment: Since the old `Account` and `Service` have been confused by using different `Accessible`. I recommend you to use a new `Account` and `Service`.

Comment: @ Land Lu - MSFT Thanks this works. But my already existing logged in users will automatically logged out when upgrade app version with above mentioned changes. Is there any way to prevent this issue.

Comment: If we already add the `Accessible = SecAccessible.Always` at first time, then this issue will not happen.