# Not able to access previous stored value in Keychain after update

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, keychain

We’re having a problem to access a value we stored previously in keychain in a previous version of our app. We have updated our Xamarin.iOS version from 11.6.14 to 12.2.1.15 and our XCode version from 9.4.1 to 10.1.

We are not able to access that value anymore after the update.

I have read there are some changes in the security settings, but I’m not able to find the specifics about that. Is there anybody that had that problem before or has lot of experience with keychain? Thanks for your help!

```
bool WriteGenericPasswordValueToSecureKeychain(string service, string account, string value)
       {
           if (service == null || account == null || value == null)
           {
               throw new ArgumentNullException("Both arguments need a value and cannot be null");
           }

           var query = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
           {
               Service = service,
               Account = account
           };

           var newRecord = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
           {
               Service = service,
               Account = account,
               ValueData = NSData.FromString(value, NSStringEncoding.UTF8)
           };

           SecStatusCode error;
           var match = SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord(query, out error);
           if (error == SecStatusCode.Success)
           {
               error = SecKeyChain.Update(match, newRecord);
           }
           else
           {
               error = SecKeyChain.Add(newRecord);
           }

           if (error != SecStatusCode.Success && error != SecStatusCode.DuplicateItem)
           {
               return false;
           }

           return true;
       }
```

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348482/how-to-resolve-xamarin-ios-seckeychain-interactionnotallowed-issue.